# Where is the actual physical storage for a Qt SQLite database?

Tags: qt, sqlite

If I setup a database like so:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setDatabaseName("data.db");
```

Where is the file actually stored? Is there a way to set this and have control over that? I have heard that you can also opt for an SQLite database to only be stored in memory, not on disk. How would you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setDatabaseName` for SQLite works just as normal filenames. Unless you specify full path, the file is created in the process' working directory.

For memory storage, try to speci.fy ":memory:" as database name. See also [Saving and restoring an in-memory SQLite database](https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/9090)